# Rails : Displaying associated model validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validates-associated

I have got three models

```
class RateCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true

  has_many :rate_card_countries, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :rate_card_details, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :countries, :through => :rate_card_countries

end

class RateCardCountry < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :country_id, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :rate_card_id, :presence => true
  belongs_to :rate_card
  belongs_to :country
end

class Country < Geography

  has_one :rate_card
  has_one :rate_card_country

end
```

In rate_cards_controller i want to create/update rate_cards such that one country should have one rate_card..
For that i have added uniqueness validation in RateCardCountry Model.
And NOw i want to display the error in rate_card_controller while creating/updating rate_cards..
Needed help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your intention correctly, you are trying to build a one-to-many relationship between RateCard and Country. In other words- a country will have only one RateCard, and a RateCard can belong to many countries.
Assuming that's the case, you really don't need the RateCardCountry model (which will be useful if you wanted it to be a many-to-many relationship).

You will need to have:

```
class RateCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  belongs_to :rate_card
end
```

And make sure you have county_id foreign key in the RateCard table.

and then:

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :rate_card
end
```

Also, it seems that right now you have:

```
class Country < Geography
```

I am not sure if you are subclassing from a Geography class, as you have not provided the rest of the code.

Hope that helps.